# SQL to find highest value from multiple columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

So, there are five different types of transaction a customer can have with a company. Each type is stored in it's own table. I need to find the date and type of the most recent transaction.

Option A: Combine all the tables into a single table and then simply run a `MAX()` function on the CreatedDate field.

Option B: Do it all in the query.

I knew Option A would work, but wanted to learn something, so I decided to try Option B.

Some Googling uncovered the `GREATEST` SQL function, that would have been exactly what I needed to solve this problem. Too bad Marketing Cloud SQL doesn't support the function.

So the only way I could think of to do it was with some really big `CASE` statements. Kept getting `NULL` returns, until a little more Googling reminded me that the comparisons I'd setup don't work with `NULL` values, so added `ISNULL` to them.

So this seemed to work, but I'm just wondering if there was a third option I didn't think of?

Also wondering which of the two solutions people think was better, A or B. I know it's subjective, but interested to hear opinions.

```
,CASE
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN 'PL'
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN 'MP'
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN 'IS'
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN 'MO'
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN 'RF'
    ELSE NULL
END AS Most_Recent_Sub_Type
,CASE
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN MAX(pls.CreatedDate)
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN MAX(hps.CreatedDate)
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN MAX(iss.CreatedDate)
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN MAX(mrs.CreatedDate)
    WHEN 
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(hps.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(iss.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(mrs.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) AND
        MAX(ISNULL(slr.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1')) > MAX(ISNULL(pls.CreatedDate,'2000-1-1'))
        THEN MAX(slr.CreatedDate)
    ELSE NULL
END AS Most_Recent_Sub_Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: For questions about queries like this -- please include the necessary details about the source Data Extension schemas *and* a sample of the desired output.  I made some assumptions about both of those in my answer.

I'd join all of the transaction Data Extensions together and utilize a partition to pick the row for each customer:

```sql
select top 1 with ties
 t.customerId
,t.orderNbr
,t.createdDate
,t.type
from (

  select customerId,orderNbr,createdDate,type from pls_transactions union all
  select customerId,orderNbr,createdDate,type from hps_transactions union all
  select customerId,orderNbr,createdDate,type from iss_transactions union all
  select customerId,orderNbr,createdDate,type from mrs_transactions union all
  select customerId,orderNbr,createdDate,type from slr_transactions 

) t
order by row_number() over (partition by t.customerId order by t.createdDate desc)
```

Translation: Sort all of the transactions by customerId and number them in descending createdDate order.  Pick the top 1 for each customerId.

You can try it yourself with this SQL Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/DXMp7wqm